# Does Firebase Actually use the iOS Bundle Id for Anything?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I just attempted to create an new App Id for my paid Apple Developer account, on developer.apple.com. The Bundle Id I tried to use was already taken by my previous free Apple Developer account, [so I had to use a different Bundle Id](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/237445#237445), which I did.

In my Xcode project I updated to my new Bundle Id everywhere I could find, Project settings, Info.plist and the GoogleService-Info.plist for Google SDK Authentication and Authorization. My app uses Firebase, my app still works entirely correct, I able to Login with existing account stored in Firebase Database and create new accounts that are correctly created in Firebase.

I then logged into Firebase, which I have been using with my app for a while, I created this Firebase project when I was using my free Apple Developer account. this Firebase project has my iOS app listed with the old Bundle Id:
[image]

There is no way to edit this on Firebase Bundle Id, I have to create a new Firebase App within the Firebase Project as I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841428/changing-bundle-id-for-firebase).

To recap, I have I changed the Bundle Id in my App source code everywhere I could find to change it. I used Xcode to Clean & Build, I deleted the App from my test device and reinstalled and everything still works against the Firebase backend.

My question is:
**Does Firebase actually use the iOS Bundle Id for anything other than a name for an App in a Firebase Project?**

Comment: Any more leads on this one?

Comment: @Sunkas no additional information, other than, from my experience using the same Firebase account for two different iOS app bundle ids in the iTunes app store it seems that Firebase does not use the iOS Bundle Id for another other than the name of project...

Comment: same experience. Changed iOS bundle ID  and firebase still works. So I think it  does not uses bundle ID except of its own referencing and unique indexing