# how to change package name and bundle ID in firebase project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a flutter project that uses firebase and I have everything linked up perfectly but now I change the package name and bundle id from com.example to com.mycompanyname and I need to do the same for iOS and Android in firebase console but im not finding instructions of how to do that.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201196/changing-firebase-package-name for Android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841428/changing-bundle-id-for-firebase for iOS (read all answers there)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create NEW app in firebase for android with NEW package name and NEW ios app with NEW bundle id. Then you need reconnect you flutter app to the new firebase projects. Easiest way [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#install-cli-tools). After that, your flutter project must has new configuration that is looking to your new firebase projects.

Comment: this worked, its such a shame firebase doesn't offer an easy solution for changing a bundle Id as its so common to change your app name during the development process

Comment: That is the solution for "changing" those attributes, since the package name and bundle id uniquely identify an app in Android and iOS respectively, and consequently should they change it means they are different apps.

Comment: @pcba-dev
absolutly correct. but this is the only way because you can't change package/bundleId in firebase project.